# Why can't I use column name in seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I try to make a barplot, where I want to display average for each `genre` within each`genre_range`.
The issue is I get an error: *ValueError: Could not interpret input 'genre_range'*
The same for 'Mean' column. Looks like 'genre_range' is not a column in this data frame, don't know why.

```
result=df_cat.groupby(['genre','genre_range']).agg(
    Mean=('danceability', np.mean),
    Count=('danceability', np.count_nonzero))
sns.barplot(x='genre_range', y='Mean', data=result, hue='genre')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that seaborn looks for 'genre' and 'genre_range' in the columns of the dataframe, but they are index levels.

An alternative is to store the levels of the indexes in new columns and use these newly created columns to plot the barplot.

```
result=df_cat.groupby(['genre','genre_range']).agg(
    Mean=('danceability', np.mean),
    Count=('danceability', np.count_nonzero))
result['xvals'] = result.index.get_level_values(level='genre_range')
result['huevals'] = result.index.get_level_values(level='genre')
sns.barplot(x='xvals', y='Mean', data=result, hue='hue')
```